# Ruby way of writing this spec in "Rspec"

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

I was wondering if there is any Ruby way of writing the following views spec(without using Capybara/Cucumber/Webrat helpers. Should be just in rspec or rspec-rails):

```
expect(rendered).to include("<input class='toggle_m' name='result_configuration[information]' type='checkbox' value='1'>")

expect(rendered).to include("<textarea class=details' disabled='disabled' name=result_configuration[info][]'></textarea>")
```

Thing is, I need to see if the the checkbox is checked(means the value is "1", value is set to "0" when it is unchecked) then textarea should be disabled. Any idea?

Or How would you write this expectation in a more readable way? Suggestions are most welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use Capybara? I find it simplifies exactly this problem.

Comment: The reason is the project owner isn't up for adding a new gem as if for now, for no specific reason. I tried to explain, but no luck.

Comment: Bad luck! Fair enough, well your ways pretty good, my only other suggestion would be to use a regex, your way might be more readable though, I'll throw an answer up to demonstrate.

Comment: A checkbox is "on" when its `checked` attribute is set.

Comment: @Stefan - I am not sure what you're trying to say here. Are you talking about the value(which is "1")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a regex, but I think your method is good enough.

```
expect(rendered).should =~ /<input[^>]*name='result_configuration[information]'[^>]*value='1'[^>]*>/
expect(rendered).should =~ /<textarea[^>]*disabled='disabled'[^>]*name=result_configuration[info][][^>]*>
```

Limitations of this method are that if there are any checked checkboxes and any disabled textareas it will pass, to do anything more I would definitely require capybara or something to actually parse the html ([regexes are not parsers](http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/do_NOT_parse_using_regexp.html))

EDIT: Added the `name=` part into both regexes as a response to the comment. Only advantage of this method is that it won't break if you change the class of the elements. Unfortunately I don't know any better solution other than external gems.

Comment: Hey, I appreciate that you took some time to answer. However, this should be only for checkbox where `name = result_configuration[information]` and textarea's `name=result_configuration[info][]`.

Comment: fair enough, I'll throw them into the regex, do you know that that will always be in that order? (if not you'll need to use an or for both the case when it's before and when it's after)

Comment: Oh, I read the update later after commenting above. I too prefer capybara for more DOM level expectation. I thought if anybody knows a better way of writing this spec in more readable way. Yes, they will always be in that order.

Comment: yep. I'd be interested if anyone can come up with a clean solution without using capybara e.t.c. I'll check back sometime to see if anyone can.

Answer (score 1):

Writing such tests for the sake of testing and coverage will only make it difficult for someone inheriting the codebase. I have written such tests only to remove them later as changes to UI are more frequent and having such tests slows down developer. if i had to still write them in OO way i would design it on the lines of pageobjects (that's a gem) - wrapper class over dom and few generic helper functions. Also adding a new gem in test group using Gemfile/bundler would not affect production servers.